# variables not set, defaulting to a blank string for vars that i dont even have in my project

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, warnings

I'm getting warnings when running my Docker Compose setup that look like this:

```
time="2023-07-16T14:57:07+02:00" level=warning msg="The \"R4cvx\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
time="2023-07-16T14:57:07+02:00" level=warning msg="The \"JeC0\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
```

These warnings repeat multiple times. I have tried adding these variables to the environment section in my docker-compose.yaml file with blank values:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
   dev_db:
      image: mysql:8
      command: >
         bash -c "
         --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password &&
         npx prisma generate --schema=src/prisma/schema.prisma &&
         npx prisma db push --schema=src/prisma/schema.prisma"
      environment:
         MYSQL_DATABASE: votemate_dev
         MYSQL_USER: votemate
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: votemate
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
         R4cvx: ''
         JeC0: ''
      ports:
         - '3308:3306'
      volumes:
         - dev_db_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

However, the warnings persist. I have also tried searching my entire project for these variables but found nothing. I'm not sure where Docker Compose is getting these variables from or why it's expecting them.

Comment: That `command:` looks strange; `--default-authentication-plugin=...` doesn't seem like a shell command that `bash -c` would understand.  Do you need to run the `prisma` commands out of a separate container that has your Node application built into it?  What code uses the oddly-named environment variables?

Comment: @DavidMaze even if i delete command from compose file it still sends this warnings, and **in my code noting uses these variables**  `R4cvx` nad `JeC0`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem:

```
...msg="The \"wtf\" variable is not set. Default to a blank string."
```

It started after I created `.env` file and put some tokens here. I found out that one of my tokens contains that "variable", something like `..$wtf..` which was cousing the warning.

I escaped the dollar with double dollars `$$wtf` and the warning message no longer shows :-)

Hope it will help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).